# Anaconda character encoding

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, anaconda, anaconda3

I am trying to connect to a postgres database using fastapi. I want to set an environmental variable that needs to have the encoding for the @ sign which is %40.

Whenever I try and set the variable anaconda changes %40 to set0. I do not know if it uses a different encoding. If so where can I find them for anaconda

Comment: Please share a [mre] that demonstrates this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because Anaconda is interpreting %40 as a special character or command.

You can try enclosing your environmental variable in quotes, like this:

```
export MY_ENV_VAR="http://myuser:mypassword%40mydatabase"
```

Comment: It is still changing the %40 to 0. I found a fix I used %%%%40. Since I want fastapi to read that and use the encoded character in the url I needed to use %%%%40. Two percent signs would do the job if it was not for that.